# Correct way to escape a subprocess call in python

Tags: python, sed

I am having problems correctly escaping a subprocess call

I want to call `sed -n "$=" /path/to/file` to count the number of lines in a file but fail to do so from python. My code is as follows:

```
import subprocess

filename = "/path/to/file"

cmd = subprocess.Popen(["sed", "-n '$='", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd_out, cmd_err = cmd.communicate()
num_lines = int(cmd_out.strip())

print num_lines
```

I have tried different escaping combinations for "-n '$='" but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think this mental model is helpful to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70668916/247696

Answer (score 4):

`-n` and `$=` are two separate arguments.

```
["sed", "-n", "$=", filename]
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought the arguments are passed in a single string not as a list.

Answer (score 1):

By default, subprocess.Popen has shell=False.

Without invoking the shell, each argument is passed uninterpreted to sed
So sed reads arguments as -n '$='

When you run the command sed -n '$=' , shell removes the '' before sending to the command sed.

So your $= should be without quotes

And as specified by Ignacio, -n $= arguments should be separate

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["sed", "-n", "$=", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```