# Python Subprocess: Unable to Escape Quotes

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, quotes

I know similar questions have been asked before, but they all seem to have been resolved by reworking how arguments are passed (i.e. using a list, etc).

However, I have a problem here in that I don't have that option. There is a particular command line program (I am using a Bash shell) to which I must pass a quoted string. It cannot be unquoted, it cannot have a replicated argument, it just has to be either single or double quoted.

```
command -flag 'foo foo1'
```

I cannot use `command -flag foo foo1`, nor can I use `command -flag foo -flag foo1`. I believe this is an oversight in how the command was programmed to receive input, but I have no control over it.

I am passing arguments as follows:

```
self.commands = [
                self.path,
                '-flag1', quoted_argument,
                '-flag2', 'test',
                ...etc...
                ]
process = subprocess.Popen(self.commands, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
results = process.communicate(input)
```

Where `quoted_argument` is something like 'foo foo1 foo2'.
I have tried escaping the single quote (`"\'foo foo1 foo2\'"`), but I get no output.

I know this is considered bad practice because it is ambiguous to interpret, but I don't have another option. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `quoted_argument` can you show us the string you are actually putting into the command? Its puzzling that your example is `command -flag 'foo foo1'` but `self.commands` have different flags. But... just doing `quoted_argument = "foo foo1"` (that is, remove the quotes completely) should work.

Comment: Alternately, just use the shell `Popen("command -flag 'foo foo1'", shell=True)`.

Comment: I was trying to generalize with the command, the actual command is a bit different. I am actually getting a list and concatenating it down into that quoted parameter, so it's a bit complicated to show. I also would prefer not to concatenate the string for shell=True if I don't have to. I'll try removing the quotes.

Comment: @tdelaney Removing quotes seems to work, thanks. You can put that as an answer and I'll accept it, or I can just do it myself if you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell breaks command strings into lists. The quotes tell the shell to put multiple words into a single list item. Since you are building the list yourself, you add the words as a single item without the quotes.

These two `Popen` commands are equivalent

```
Popen("command -flag 'foo foo1'", shell=True)
Popen(["command", "-flag", "foo foo1"])
```

**EDIT**

This answer deals with escaping characters in the shell. If you don't use the shell, you don't add any quotes or escapes, just put in the string itself. There are other issues with skipping the shell, like piping commands, running background jobs, using shell variables and etc. These all can be done in python instead of the shell.

Comment: note: the first `Popen()` call runs an intermediate shell process. The second one *does not run the shell* before starting the `command`.

Comment: The addition of a shell is potentially a significant change. See [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: @tripleee - there are several issues with `shell=True` and its good to point that out. But this question was specifically about the use of quotes in the parameters not the shell in general.

Comment: Sure; still, it's not entirely correct to say the two are equivalent. This is a good candidate for a canonical answer, as the topic comes up a lot, but many of the questions are unclear or unfocused. But then it would be nice to also cover this nuance properly.

Comment: @tripleee - Feel free to post a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

### A mental model of process and shells that I found very helpful:

This mental model has helped me a lot through the years.

Processes in your operating system receive an array of strings representing the arguments. In Python, this array can be accessed from `sys.argv`. In C, this is the `argv` array passed to the `main` function. And so on.

When you open a terminal, you are running a shell inside that terminal, for example `bash` or `zsh`. What happens if you run a command like this one?

```
$ /usr/bin/touch one two
```

What happens is that the shell interprets the command that you wrote and splits it by whitespace to create the array `["/usr/bin/touch", "one", "two"]`. It then launches a new process using that list of arguments, in this case creating two files named `one` and `two`.

What if you wanted one file named `one two` with a space? You can't pass the shell a list of arguments as you might want to do, you can only pass it a string. Shells like Bash and Zsh use single quotes to workaround this:

```
$ /usr/bin/touch 'one two'
```

The shell will create a new process with the arguments `["/usr/bin/touch", "one two"]`, which in this case create a file named `one two`.

Shells have special features like piping. With a shell, you can do something like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/echo 'This is an example' | /usr/bin/tr a-z A-Z
THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
```

In this case, the shell interprets the `|` character differently. In creates a process with the arguments `["/usr/bin/echo", "This is an example"]` and another process with the arguments `["/usr/bin/tr", "a-z", "A-Z"]`, and will pipe the output of the former to the input of the latter.

### How this applies to `subprocess` in Python

Now, in Python, you can use `subprocess` with `shell=False` (which is the default, or with `shell=True`. If you use the default behaviour `shell=False`, then `subprocess` expects you to pass it a list of arguments. You cannot use special shell features like shell piping. On the plus side, you don't have to worry about escaping special characters for the shell:

```
import subprocess
# create a file named "one two"
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/touch", "one two"])
```

If you do want to use shell features, you can do something like:

```
subprocess.call(
    "/usr/bin/echo 'This is an example' | /usr/bin/tr a-z A-Z",
    shell=True,
)
```

If you are using variables with no particular guarantees, remember to escape the command:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

subprocess.call(
    "/usr/bin/echo " + shlex.quote(variable) + " | /usr/bin/tr a-z A-Z",
    shell=True,
)
```

(Note that [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) is only designed for UNIX shells, and not for DOS on Windows.)

Comment: Note that I was mainly talking about UNIX-like systems in my answer. The answer should be similar in Windows, but the details about how processes are launched on Windows are different, and Windows doesn't ship with Bash or Zsh by default.